# Парсинг XML файла и дальнейшее его преобразование

Tags: javascript, html

Я делаю веб-читалку и храню данные, к примеру, текстового файла, в локальном хранилище. Решил добавить ещё и FB2 формат, считывая XML. Проблема в том, что когда я записываю данные XML в локальное хранилище, то само собой локальное хранилище по понятным причинам просто не справляется с хранением стольких символов. Можно ли как-то преобразовать XML в обычный текст с помощью обычного JS?

Comment: Можно преобразовать. Но лучше хранить большие данные в indexedDb.

Comment: А как именно преобразовать? Скажите хотя бы в каком направлении думать.

Comment: Для парсинга XML можете использовать `DOMParser`